# Spring boot start on listening to messages on application start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, messaging

I have a Spring Boot application that starts listening on Azure IOT Hub at application start. It is done this way:

```
@EventListener
public void subscribeEventMessages(ContextRefreshedEvent event)  {
    client
            .receive(false) // set this to false to read only the newly available events
            .subscribe(this::hubAllEventsCallback);
}
```

My problem is, that this uses `ContextRefreshedEvent` but in fact i only want to start it once on application start.
I also checked other methods how start something at the beginning, like `CommandLineRunner`.

On the other hand if implementing listeners for more standard stuff like JMS there are specific Annotations like `@JmsListener` or providing Beans of specific Types.

My question is: Can i leverage some of these more message(subscribe) related mechanisms to start my method?

Comment: cannot you just make it singleshot (flag + ifstatement) ?

Comment: what you mean with single shot - how?

Comment: Just react once to context refreshed event (which happens on application startup) and ignore rest of events. If you need to use it more than once, you can create custom annotation for that as well.

Comment: Why/do you *really* don't want to re-subscribe at "refresh"? Please explain the demand/issue more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't want our `@EventListener` to listen on "context refresh" but only on "context start", please (try) replace:

- [`ContextRefreshEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html)
- with [`ContextStartEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStartedEvent.html)

...which is "sibling class" with exactly this semantical difference.

Comment: CommandLineRunner/InitializingBean's also cool: but (by default) run also on refresh!..and my guess: the same issue (refresh vs start), you will also encounter with `@JmsListener`(?)

Comment: Regarding "ContextStartEvent" i was not sure: docu states "Event raised when an ApplicationContext gets started." but this is not "... is started" right?

Comment: (of course) nothing "spring like" can start before "context" started, so it means "immediately at/after".